# Programmatically Add Features for Role assignment in Ubercart Drupal 7 product node

Tags: ubercart

I am trying to create a product programmatically and set it features for role assignment, that a user gets a specific role after he purchases, i tried all the ways i can but couldnt get it working. below is the code i used for adding it, but when i edit the feature for role assignment it doesnt hold the values i set in the edit feature form.

```
function add_product_feature($nid, $sku){
     // Insert new product into the uc_product_features tables
     $desc = "<strong>SKU:</strong> ".$sku."<br /><strong>Role:
     </strong>purchaser<br /><strong>Expiration:</strong> <a 
      href=\"/admin/store/settings/products\">Global expiration</a> 
      (not overridden)<br /><strong>Shippable:</strong> No<br />
      <strong>Multiply by quantity:</strong> No";
      $nid1 = db_insert('uc_product_features')
      ->fields(array('nid' => $nid,'fid' => 'role','description' => 
      $desc, 
      ))
      ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Inserting into the DB directly can cause you problems down the road; there's already been code written to do what you're trying to do.

Look at the [uc_roles functions/documentation](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_roles%21uc_roles.module/7) and follow how it adds product features via [`uc_roles_feature_form_submit`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_roles%21uc_roles.module/function/uc_roles_feature_form_submit/7) submission handler and its [`uc_product_feature_save()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_product%21uc_product.module/function/uc_product_feature_save/7) call.